# How to limit commit size in svn through pre commit hook in windows

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

How to limit commit size in svn through pre commit hook in windows.

Hi I'd like to limit the size of my repository by specifying a maximum size, however I cannot find any information on doing so.

Is this technically possible?

Comment: Can you please clarify "maximum size"? Do you want to limit the disk space used by the repository, or the number of files in it, or the number of changes in a commit etc?

Comment: Why do you think you need to do this in the first place? It is not technically possible to accurately predict the size of your repository  based upon an incoming commit.